# TinkerPop: Find minimum and maximum relationship length over a big graphs

Tags: tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

**Objective: Find the minimum and maximum relationship lengths between two Node Types.**

Example: Following are the dummy connections for a Node type 'T'

(Aplha)-->(Bravo)

(Bravo)-->(Charlie)

So the minimum hops to reach two nodes is 1 (i.e. Aplha is directly linked to Charlie), and the maximum hops to reach two nodes is 2 (i.e. (Aplha)--(Beta)--(Charlie)).

Query I have is like:

```
g.V().hasLabel("Process").as("from", "to")
.repeat(both().as("to").dedup("from", "to")).emit(hasLabel("Process"))
.hasLabel("Process")
// I was unable to get only min and max, using both min and max did not work so I made a work-around (.as("len").max().dedup()) 
.select(all, "to").count(local).as("count").math("count - 1").as("len").dedup()
```

This is pretty slow as compared to using [NEO4J APOC as in this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49174562/1897935)

Is there any way to achieve this operations is a faster way?

**Solutions I CANNOT use:**

Limit relationship length: I have to use it at n levels, so cannot limit it to 3 or 4 levels.

Comment: google group post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/gPLATDP3s3Q